# Conditional Formatting in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I want to conditionally change the color of a font or text box background color or rectangles background color on a certain value. As far as i have researched its only possible in a matrix or a table. Is there any way i can do this? I want to change the color of the "condition" box on bases of a value, please see the attached screen shot. I would be very thankful if anyone can help me achieve it or any other work around to achieve this.[image]

Comment: You could try using a single cell table/matrix as a last resort. Or writing a [custom visual](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-custom-visuals/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the Custom Visual: Card with States. It's States properties let you dynamically control the colors of the font or background.

https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA104380967?src=office&tab=Overview